# DefaultValue in materila ui DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[check this attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azfmu.png)

```
 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider
      utils={DateFnsUtils}
      required={required}
      error={!!(touched && error)}
    >
      <DatePicker
        leftArrowIcon={<KeyboardArrowLeft/>}
        rightArrowIcon={<KeyboardArrowRight/>}
        className={className}
        {...restProps}
        format="MMMM Do yyyy"
        margin="normal"
        label={label}
        value={value || selectedDate}
        onChange={(event, value) => input.onChange(event, value)}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

I have material ui `DatePicker` compoennt which have as u see some default value , in my case it is `2000-01-01T00:00:00` this date , I want to get as default value in field for example text `MM-DD-YYYY` , when I pass it in value prop, I get error,

> `Incorrect input format`

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have correctly formatted date string using `Date` in Javascript.
Look at this [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lxlnj6xwrq)